# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I'm returning `YES` in my view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` function, and I can see using breakpoints that `YES` is being returned, however the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method isn't being called, and nor is any other rotating method. It seems like after returning `YES` nothing happens!

Any ideas?

Mike

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is this views viewController a subview of some other root view controller thats not a navigation controller? if so then the call does not propagate to the subviews controller, so that might be why your view isnt rotating.

Comment: I'm trying to handle the calls in a table view controller that is the root of a navigation controller, which itself is a tab in a tab controller. Is that the right place to detect it?

Answer (score 18):

I have a similar problem and saw Daniel's answer however I can't find any confirmation of this in the developer documentation. Not that I don't believe the answer but I don't really understand why the orientation call does not propagate.

Someone gave me a trick that works using something like this:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(detectOrientation) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: Ask the latter part as a new question, because it doesn't belong in an answer.  No one will be able to help you here.

Comment: I find my question too similar to the OP's to make a new question, the trick works and solved my problem. I was wondering out of curiosity more than necessity. Thanks though.

Comment: All you need to do is link back to this question and answer in your new question, then ask your additional question.  People will be able to read the context of this question in order to answer yours, and I bet you'll get a decent answer from someone.  Stack Overflow is not a traditional discussion forum, and questions asked within answers tend to get deleted to keep the site clean.

Comment: I don't really see any substantive difference between his question and the OP's.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to look for is I found if I had `UIPopoverController` called in `[UINavigationController viewDidAppear]`, then `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` are not called.  It looks like `UIPopoverController` being modal blocks the rotation method calls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes me too. Ok, it won't get called in a sub-viewcontroller - have to pass it down. Can deal with that. And the notification idea works well *except* that you only get "did..." not "will..." (afaik) and anyway it's a messy solution to a problem which shouldn't be there.

My mistake was to call `[super loadView]` in my loadView. [Not supposed to do that](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1). When I removed `[super loadView]` and alloc'd the view myself `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` started working.

What's really weird is that the `[super loadView]` was in the *sub-viewcontroller* and the event wasn't even reaching the top one...

Answer (score 2):

If you are not receiving callbacks on `willAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` in any view controller, add the view controller as your root view controller's child view controller.

For Eg; say `self.viewController` is your root view controller and `childViewController` is the view controller in which you want to get auto-rotation callbacks, add the following line of code;

`[self.viewController addChildViewController:childViewController];`

Actually, adding as the child view controller to any view controller which gets rotation call backs will work too.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation

> At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation. After the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the app uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window.

So if you are using a TabBarViewController be carefull to set up the selected view in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.