# Rotating UIView - willRotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to autorotate a view and I have the same problem explained here:
[willRotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516268/willrotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called).

Even though I implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and returned YES, in every `UIViewController` subclass I implemented; `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not being called.

Perhaps somebody could tell me what I'm missing. I have the following View Controllers structure (I hope this is clear enough..):

```
NavigationController (Programatically) 
     -with root > TabBarController (Programatically) 
                  -with tab item > NavigationController (Programatically)
                                   -with root > UITableViewController (a Subclass) 
                                                -pushed to navigator controller > UIViewController (a Subclass).
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: This seems to be a fundamental iOS SDK problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try insert your controller(NavigationController) to window by rootviewcontroller.

if not works for you, use notifications UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification

**Edit**

Works:

```
// custom controller
    TestController *t = [[TestController alloc] init];

    // navigaton
    UINavigationController *controllerinsertIntoTab = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:t];

    // tab bar
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabbarController addChildViewController:controllerinsertIntoTab];

    // first navigation
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabbarController];

    [self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

special for you https://github.com/sakrist/TestControllers

i hope it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are not receiving callbacks on `willAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` in any view controller, add the view controller as your root view controller's child view controller.

For Eg; say `self.viewController` is your root view controller and `childViewController` is the view controller in which you want to get auto-rotation callbacks, add the following line of code;

`[self.viewController addChildViewController:childViewController];`

Actually, adding as the child view controller to any view controller which gets rotation call backs will work too.

Hope it helps.