# UITableCell rounded border

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my iOS app, I have a table view and I would like to customise the border of my cells. I would like to reproduce an effect like the following:

[image]

I'm developing in Swift 2.0 for iOS 9.

Comment: use cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2 cell.layer.masksToBounds = true. cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;cell.layer.borderColor = desiredcolor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720856/how-to-get-rounded-edges-on-uitableviewcells-in-a-manner-that-allows-cell-backg Check this

Comment: add border color, width, corner radius to your cell as Reshmi suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tejas Ardeshna's answer would work, but it wont look good if borders are touching view bounds.

I would suggest add a view inside content view, keeping some padding. and then apply border to this view.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if cell.viewWithTag(100) == nil
    {
        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRectInset(cell.contentView.bounds, 4 , 4)
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1).CGColor
        cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
cell?.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
cell?.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
cell?.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `borderColor`, `borderWidth` and `cornerRadius` to the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.