# iOS 6 Rotation Methods not being called

Tags: rotation, ios6

I have the following view hierarchy

- UIScrollView (horizontal scrolling)

  - UIScrollView (vertical scrolling)

    - UIViewController

In fact there is a Root ScrollView Controller which has multiple Sub ScrollViews. (the Root ScrollViewController only scrolls horizontal - the sub ones only vertical). Each Sub ScrollView has an UIViewController.

My Root ScrollView Controller works as expected and calls my rotation methods which look like the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self rotateScrollViewToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) rotateScrollViewToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        // do some rotation logic
    }
}
```

I have used the same methods in my Sub ScrollViews and UIViewControllers but they don't get called on rotation.

Anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is deprecated and will no longer be called as of iOS 6.

try to implements these following methods.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods{   
     // This method is called to determine whether to 
     // automatically forward appearance-related containment
     //  callbacks to child view controllers.
    return YES;

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods{
    // This method is called to determine whether to
    // automatically forward rotation-related containment 
    // callbacks to child view controllers.
   return YES;
}
```

note : these methods just supported in iOS 6.

Comment: ok I implemented these methods in my root scrollviewcontroller - but the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: still only gets called in my root scrollview controller.

Comment: are you implement supported orientation method ???
it should be implemented in all subview controllers

Comment: yes but it seems that it is not possible what I want to achieve -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516268/willrotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 6.0 release notes:

> Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of UIViewController is
>   deprecated. In its place, you should use the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: and shouldAutorotate methods.
>   More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now,
>   iOS containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult their
>   children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an
>   app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set
>   to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and
>   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom. A
>   view controller’s supported interface orientations can change over
>   time—even an app’s supported interface orientations can change over
>   time. The system asks the top-most full-screen view controller
>   (typically the root view controller) for its supported interface
>   orientations whenever the device rotates or whenever a view controller
>   is presented with the full-screen modal presentation style. Moreover,
>   the supported orientations are retrieved only if this view controller
>   returns YES from its shouldAutorotate method. The system intersects
>   the view controller’s supported orientations with the app’s supported
>   orientations (as determined by the Info.plist file or the app
>   delegate’s application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
>   method) to determine whether to rotate. The system determines whether
>   an orientation is supported by intersecting the value returned by the
>   app’s supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method with the value
>   returned by the supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most
>   full-screen controller. The setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method
>   is not deprecated outright. It now works only if the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most full-screen view
>   controller returns 0. This makes the caller responsible for ensuring
>   that the status bar orientation is consistent. For compatibility, view
>   controllers that still implement the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method do not get the new
>   autorotation behaviors. (In other words, they do not fall back to
>   using the app, app delegate, or Info.plist file to determine the
>   supported orientations.) Instead, the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method is used to synthesize
>   the information that would be returned by the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method.